# Make C library : pointer-style initialization or hidden state variables?

Tags: c, module, initialization

I'm developing a library. The initialization basically returns a pointer to malloced struct that holds all the lib's internal states. While it may not be uber-userful for the user to create multiple instances of the lib, it could be done if needed. The syntax looks like that :

```
myLib* lib = lib_create();
lib_function1(lib, parameter1, parameter2);
```

A lot of C libs works in another way :

```
lib_initialize();
lib_function1(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Seems less flexible for the user but also simpler, and maybe faster (not sure about that ?)

- What style do you prefer and which one do you recommend ?
- Are there performance issues with the pointer style ? (I need the best performance since it's a real time processing lib, everytime accessing a lot of internal states variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing. For maximum flexibility, you would probably want to split your `myLib` type into several functional units and have multiple `xy_create()` functions, along with the corresponding `xy_destroy()` functions. This way, you'd approach an *object oriented* interface, you can follow the *single responsibility principle* and design a really flexible interface.

If you just want to avoid global state, the solution with one "library instance" is fine. It allows the caller to create more than one instance and, what I consider more important, makes it explicit that the caller has to ensure thread safety when the same instance is shared across multiple threads.

Regarding performance, you have some overhead in the create function for `malloc()`, but you typically don't care about *one time* costs. Later, the pointer dereferences will take maybe a few CPU cycles more than a direct access. I'd say it's negligible.

Still, global static state has it's uses. If you can tell for sure that neither multiple instances nor calls from different threads could ever make sense for what your library does, go for it. It's after all the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping state variable hidden is fine when there must be only one instance of your library initialized at any time. This practice lets your library stay in control, detecting situations when it gets double-initialized. Of course, if your library is intended for use in concurrent environments, keeping shared state consistent becomes the task of your library.

When having multiple instances of your library is allowed, passing a "library handle" (`mylib *lib` in your example) becomes a valid choice. However, passing that variable around your code becomes a liability, so callers often put `lib` in a static variable, effectively doing the same the libraries with hidden state do.

As far as the performance goes, there is a slight advantage to not passing a handle, especially on tiny systems with limited resources. On most modern hardware there should be no practical difference, so the decision should be made based on the logical design considerations alone.